# How to fix the Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError zorro modal in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

***list-item.html***

```
   <nz-list
                [nzDataSource]="alerts$ | async"
                nzBordered
                nzSize="small"
                [nzItemLayout]="'horizontal'"
                [nzRenderItem]="notif"
                [nzBordered]="false"
              >
                <ng-template #notif let-item>
    <nz-list-item [nzContent]="content" (click)="openNotifModal(item)"></nz-list-item>
    </ng-template>
```

***list-item.ts***

```
@Select(AlertState.get('books')) alerts$: Observable<Partial<Books>>;
displayAlert$ = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
openNotifModal(item?: any) {
    this.displayAlert$.next(item);
  }
```

***notification-modal.ts***

```
@Input()
  set onDisplay(data: object) {
    if (data) {
      this.dataDisplayed = { ...data };
      this.openNotifModal();
    }
  }

notifModal: NzModalRef;

constructor(private modalService: NzModalService ){ }

openNotifModal(): void {
    this.notifModal = this.modalService.create({
          nzTitle: 'Message Alert',
          nzContent: 'This is a message alert'
          nzWrapClassName: 'vertical-center-modal dialog-modal',
          nzWidth: 400,
          nzMaskClosable: false,
          nzClosable: false,
          nzOnOk: () => console.log('Click ok')
        });
}
```

there's two module which is the `list-item` and `notificitaion-modal`.

When I try to click the modal this is the error message in console `ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'nzNoAnimation: undefined'. Current value: 'nzNoAnimation: false'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?`

How to fix it? cause every I click the item it has an error.

Comment: Please remove code from constructor and add in `ngAfterViewInit` hook

Comment: @Edison sorry I forgot to add a bracket and I added a new information which is there's two module which is the notification-modal and the list-item.